# Doctrine1 is removing parentheses around multiple OR conditions

Tags: sql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, doctrine-query

I have a query that filters a list of products by a price similarity like this:

```
$query->andWhere(
  '(
    (i.price > ? AND i.price < ?)
    OR (i.salePrice > ? AND i.salePrice < ?)
  )',
  array(
    $item->price*0.8,
    $item->price*1.5,
    $item->salePrice*0.8,
    $item->salePrice*1.5
  )
);
```

Unfortunately Doctrine is ignoring outer parenthesis and instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `deleted`=0 AND ( 
    (`price` > ? AND `price` < ?) OR (`saleprice` > ? AND `saleprice < ?`)
)
```

I get something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `deleted`=0 AND (`price` > ? AND `price` < ?) OR (`saleprice` > ? AND `saleprice < ?`)
```

I.e. even deleted products with sale price that fits the condition appear in the results.

Right now I am just using single `OR` condition, then it works:

```
$query->andWhere(
  '(i.price > ? AND i.price < ?)',
  array(
    $item->price*0.8,
    $item->price*1.5
  )
);
```

The resulting SQL looks like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `deleted`=0 AND `price` > ? AND `price` < ?
```

But obviously this is a bit weak. How to hold multiple `OR` conditions together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to patch Doctrine with `whereParenWrap()` function from [here](http://darrendev.blogspot.com/2010/08/putting-parentheses-into-complex.html) I had to look for another solution as this simply didn't work out. It just wrapped all `WHERE`s in parenthesis.

The solution was simple, I just added `AND TRUE` to the query outside the parentheses:

```
$query->andWhere(
  '(
    (i.price > ? AND i.price < ?)
    OR (i.salePrice > ? AND i.salePrice < ?)
  ) AND TRUE',
  ...
);
```